# License in Opensource Apache Guacamole

Tags: apache, maven, github, build

I cloned the source code from this github repository : git://github.com/glyptodon/guacamole-client.git

I am able to build successfully and use it.

I read the License agreement of this project : https://github.com/glyptodon/guacamole-client/tree/master/guacamole/src/licenses

It is mentioned as

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:

But when I add a class in it and build, It is throwing a license error :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< org.apache.guacamole:guacamole >-------------------
[INFO] Building guacamole 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ guacamole ---
[INFO] Deleting /guacamole-client/guacamole/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- apache-rat-plugin:0.12:check (validate) @ guacamole ---
[INFO] Enabled default license matchers.
[INFO] Will parse SCM ignores for exclusions...
[INFO] Parsing exclusions from /guacamole-client/guacamole/.gitignore
[INFO] Finished adding exclusions from SCM ignore files.
[INFO] 67 implicit excludes (use -debug for more details).
[INFO] Exclude: src/main/webapp/app/*/templates/*.html
[INFO] Exclude: **/*.json
[INFO] Exclude: src/licenses/**/*
[INFO] 485 resources included (use -debug for more details)
[INFO] Rat check: Summary over all files. Unapproved: 1, unknown: 1, generated: 0, approved: 419 licenses.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.115 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-18T21:45:16+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.rat:apache-rat-plugin:0.12:check (validate) on project guacamole: Too many files with unapproved license: 1 See RAT report in: /guacamole/target/rat.txt -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Attached the rat.txt for reference : https://codeshare.io/adNYMZ

Could someone help me why I am not able to override this opensource project?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Have you added the corresponding license header to the new class?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the license header in the file

```
src/main/java/org/apache/guacamole/rest/auth/TutorialAuthenticationProvider.java
```

The Guacamole pom.xml is configured to use RAT, which checks all files for the presence of the license text. If the license is not included, the build will fail.

You can also disable RAT with option `-Drat.skip=true` or add your file to the exclusion list in pom.xml (this is useful for some resource files that do not need a license).